# How to allow images from facebook cdn in Ionic app?

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, content-security-policy

I suddenly can't load profile images from Facebook (https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net) in my Ionic 1 app (Firebase auth with Facebook provider). This has worked before, but now I just get a blank image (probably some sort of 4xx error code?). Both iOS and Android.

I have the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` installed, and my `config.xml` has `<access origin="*"/>`.

I have tried to add the `content-security-policy` meta-tag without any luck:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src *  blob: android-webview-video-poster: cdvphotolibrary:  'self' data: ws: wss://*; default-src * blob: 'self' gap: wss: ws: data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * http: https: ws: wss://*;">
```

Any ideas? I know that this has previously worked, so there might have been some changes in Cordova or iOS/Android causing this?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**:

I tried to use other external images, for instance a random one from a newspaper, and i worked. Can this be a Facebook-auth error, of some sort?

```
ionic info
--------------------------------
--------------------------------

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X Sierra
Node Version: v4.4.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around the problem by fetching the profile image manually. The image provided by the Firebase SDK still doesn't work.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    if (profile.providerId === "facebook.com") {
      user.updateProfile({
        photoURL : "https://graph.facebook.com/" + profile.uid + "/picture?height=200"
      });
    }
  });
}
```